# How to mimic AsyncTask for displaying a loading dialog in Android?

Tags: java, android, asynchronous

I've seen some of the answers to similar questions on here but they aren't working for me.

What I want to do is start a Thread and run some code in it, but before I start the thread, I want to display a loading dialog, and as soon as the thread is finished running, close the loading dialog.

So something like this:

```
LoadingDialog dialog = new LoadingDialog(MainActivity.this);

class MyThread {
    ...
    void send() {
        dialog.displayDialog();

        // DO THINGS HERE
        new Thread((Runnable) () -> {
            try{
                ...
            } catch (...) {
            }
        }).start();

        // Close the dialog with dialog.closeDialog();
    }
}
```

(`displayDialog()` and `closeDialog()` are just methods I created in my LoadingDialog class to start and dismiss the dialogs)

I'm not sure exactly how to do this, I've seen some uses of handler on this site but they're all different and not working for me so I'm a little stuck.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    LoadingDialog dialog;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        dialog = new LoadingDialog(MainActivity.this);

        MyThread myThread = new MyThread(MainActivity.this);
        myThread.start();
    }

    static class MyThread extends Thread {

        private WeakReference<MainActivity> activityRef;

        public MyThread(MainActivity activity) {
            activityRef = new WeakReference<>(activity);
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            send();
        }

        void send() {
            // Display dialog
            if (getActivity() != null) {
                getActivity().dialog.displayDialog();
            }

            // DO THINGS HERE
            // TODO: Write your code that execute in a background here

            // Close dialog
            if (getActivity() != null) {
                getActivity().dialog.closeDialog();
            }
        }

        private MainActivity getActivity() {
            return activityRef.get();
        }
    }
}
```